# Valor decimal com 5 casas decimais no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação `(Asp.NET MVC 5.2.3.0, EF 6.1.3 e SQL Server 2012)`, o banco de dados possui uma tabela com o campo `decimal(6, 5)`, quando salvo um valor neste campo `-2,56478` por exemplo no banco ele fica `-2,56000`. A `Collation do banco é SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`.

Será que é configuração do SQL Server ou do EF? Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Comment: você já tentou debugar para ver o que esta indo para o banco?

Comment: Já, o valor vai como -2.56478. Já configurei o webconfig: <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />.

Comment: Abaixo o resultado do Profiler: exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[TABELA]
SET [CAMPO01] = @0, [CAMPO02] = @1, [CAMPO03] = @2, [CAMPO04] = @3, [Latitude] = @4, [CAMPO05] = @5, [CAMPO06] = @6, [CAMPO07] = @7
WHERE ([ID] = @8)
',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 datetime2(7),@3 int,@4 decimal(18,2),@5 decimal(18,2),@6 tinyint,@7 nvarchar(max) ,@8 int',@0=1001,@1=1029,@2='2016-02-17 00:00:00',@3=208,@4=-1.25,@5=-65.25,@6=2,@7=N'Qualquer coisa...',@8=2763.

Comment: Poste a parte onde você faz o `insert` e se for `proc` poste a  `proc `também,  o que mais parece ser é o tipo no campo `@4 decimal(18,2),@5 decimal(18,2)` , veja é só tem duas casas de alguma forma isso vai arredondar seu valor.

Answer (score 0):

Somente para deixar registrado, o problema que citei acima foi devido a geração do ORM ter sido gerado via Engenharia Reversa (EF PowerTools), infelizmente não sei dizer se foi a versão da ferramenta que estou usando atualmente, ainda não testei. Mais o problema foi solucionado fazendo a engenharia reversa com CodeFirst (Code First from database) presente a partir do Update 2 do Visual Studio 2013 e do EntityFramework 6.1.

Abaixo o resultado do profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[TABELA]
SET [CAMPO01] = @0, [CAMPO02] = @1, [CAMPO03] = @2, [CAMPO04] = @3, **[Latitude] = @4**, [Longitude] = @5, [CAMPO05] = @6, [CAMPO06] = @7
WHERE ([ID] = @8)
',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 datetime2(7),@3 int,**@4 decimal(6,5)**,@5 decimal(7,5),@6 tinyint,@7 varchar(max) ,@8 int',@0=1001,@1=1029,@2='2016-02-17 00:00:00',@3=208,@4=-1.25789,@5=-65.25698,@6=2,@7='Olá, Mundo...',@8=2763, agora a precision e scale são reconhecida pois no Context criado foi acrescido .HasPrecision(6, 5).
```